# Understanding a Specific Instance of Leibniz's Law in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm currently studying discrete mathematics and working on exercises related to
**Leibniz's law:**
$$\frac{X=Y}{E[z:=X]=E[z:=Y]}$$

I've come across a particular problem that I'm struggling to understand:

> Below, are a number of instantiations of Leibniz, with parts missing.
> Fill in the missing parts and write down what the expression $E$ is.

$$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot{x}+7\cdot{y}=?}$$

Here's what I've tried so far:

Step 1. $$E=x\cdot z+y\cdot z$$
Step 2. $$\frac{7=y+1}{E[z:=7]=E[z:=y+1]}$$
Step 3. $$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot x+7\cdot y=x\cdot (y+1)+y\cdot (y+1)}$$
$${\mathrm{Answer:}}\ x\cdot (y+1)+y\cdot (y+1)$$

But according to the textbook, there should be **three answers.**

Could someone please explain the logic behind this problem and how to approach it using Leibniz's law?
Are there any underlying principles or theorems that I should be aware of to solve this problem?

My textbook is ["A Logical Approach to Discrete Mathematics"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3837-7).
Any insights, explanations, or references to relevant material would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the deduction $$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot{x}+7\cdot{y}=?}$$
to be an instance of Leibniz's law, $X$ must be $7$ and $Y$ must be $y+1$.

The reason that there are three possible answers is that $7$ appears twice on the left hand side of the conclusion. So either of the two $7$s, or both of them, could have been obtained from substituting $X$ for $z$.

Here are the three possibilities for $E$, and the corresponding deductions:

(1) $E: z\cdot x + 7\cdot y$

$$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot x + 7\cdot y=(y+1)\cdot x + 7\cdot y}$$

(2) $E: 7\cdot x + z\cdot y$

$$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot x + 7\cdot y=7\cdot x + (y+1)\cdot y}$$

(3) $E: z\cdot x + z\cdot y$

$$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot x + 7\cdot y=(y+1)\cdot x + (y+1)\cdot y}$$

---

Now in my opinion, there is actually a fourth valid solution, corresponding to the case that neither of the $7$s were obtained from a substitution - they were both already present in $E$.

(4) $E: 7\cdot x + 7\cdot y$

$$\frac{7=y+1}{7\cdot x + 7\cdot y=7\cdot x + 7\cdot y}$$

Indeed, in this case, $E$ does not contain the variable $z$, so $E[z := X]$ and $E[z := y]$ are both just $E$.

Of course, this is a rather silly application of Leibniz's law, since the conclusion does not really use the premise. But it is a valid instance of the rule.